# Проблема с проверкой (for, if, JSON)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Проблема такова:
Написал проверку на наличие значения объекта, но проверку он проходит мягко говоря плохо.
Если на чистоту, он её проверяет лишь 1 раз, и лишь первый ключ (его значение). Если смотреть на код
то всё логично, но почему-то он не проверят последующие ключи (их значения), и выполняет else
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="create"><h2>Создать шаблон</h2></div>

var addBtn = document.querySelector(".create");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var a = textTempName.value.trim() == "";
    var b = textTempContent.value.trim() == "";
    var c = textTempName.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    var d = textTempContent.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    if(!a && !b) {
        if(config["templates"].length != 0) {
            config["templates"].forEach((x) => {
                if(x.name == c) {
                    return alert(`Шаблон "${c}" занят.`)
                } else {
                    newTemp(c,d);
                    //return alert(`Шаблон "${c}" добавлен.`)
                }
            })
        } else {
            newTemp(c,d)
        }
    } else {
        alert("Ошибка!\nПроверьте все поля.")
    }
    
});
```

В JSON:

```
{
    "templates": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "content": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код текстом, а не изображением, это увеличит вероятность того, что вам хотя бы попытаются помочь.

Comment: function save() {
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/temp.json', JSON.stringify(config, null, "\t"));
}
function newTemp(title, text) {
    config["templates"].push({
        "name": title,
        "content": text
    })
    save();
}

var addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-new-temp");

Comment: addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var a = textTempName.value.trim() == "";
    var b = textTempContent.value.trim() == "";
    var c = textTempName.value.toLowerCase().trim();
    var d = textTempContent.value.toLowerCase().trim();

Comment: if(!a && !b) {
        if(config["templates"].length != 0) {
            config["templates"].forEach((x) => {
                if(x.name == c) {
                    return alert(`Шаблон "${c}" занят.`)
                } else {
                    newTemp(c,d);
                    //return alert(`Шаблон "${c}" добавлен.`)
                }
            })
        } else {
            newTemp(c,d)
        }
    } else {
        alert("Ошибка!\nПроверьте все поля.")
    }
    
});

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте **в тело вопроса** код текстом, а не изображением, это увеличит вероятность того, что вам хотя бы попытаются помочь.

Comment: Всё, сделал. Проверьте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если смотреть на код то всё логично

Нет, не логично. Вы добавляете в массив новый элемент столько раз, сколько там существующих элементов с отличающимся `name`.

Comment: То есть? Можете указать где именно я совершил ошибку?

Comment: @АлисКоролев Могу, но не хочу пeрепечатывать код с Ваших картинок.

Comment: ошибка - весь цикл, начиная с 61 строки. надо было написать `const isTemplateExists = config.templates.some(ПРОВЕРКА); if ( isTemplateExists ) { alert } else { add template to config }`

Comment: Чё так сложно то... Я плохо знаю js, извините. Поискал информацию о методе some, и сейчас у меня работает так:
добавляет объект в JSON, далеее выдает ошибку каждый раз когда пытается "найти" новый .name, как итог, одноразово. Можно статью на подробное описание some? Если нет, то сам поищу. Спасибо. P.S У меня не массив, а объекты в массиве, т.е мне нужно обращаться к ключу

Comment: Я понял почему оно не работает, и почему это не логично, как я ранее писал. До меня сейчас дошло, что он создает +n кол-во объектов, которое при проверке равное true, и если у меня будет 4 объекта, при этом ни один из их ключей не будет равен тому что я ввведу, он будет добавлять +4 одинаковых объекта, можете пожалуйста сказать, как решить такую пробелму?

Comment: @АлисКоролев Молодец! Объявить до цикла булевскую переменную `let found = false;`, в цикле проверять: `if (...name == c) { found = true; break; }`, а после цикла: `if (!found) { newTemp(c, d); }`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, правда. Сделал как Вы написали, и сейчас всё работает, я и не думал что всё можно решить так просто, ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: @АлисКоролев Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.